# Search by serialized value

Tags: php, mysql

This is the query i use for getting the data out of my database

```
SELECT
    product_description.name as name, 
    product.image as iurl
FROM
    product_description, product
WHERE
    product_description.product_id = product.product_id
    AND product.product_id
    AND product.product_id = '33';
```

1. Why is this query producing double results?
2. I want to automaticly search by multiple values (id's) stored in database instead of manually adding the `AND product.product_id='?'` part. Values are stored in **serialized** form.

something like

```
... AND product.product_id in (setting.value WHERE key='featured');
```

I know that query is not correct, just trying to show what i want.

**table 'setting':**

```
value    | key
-------------------
23,43,28 | featured
```

Comment: `FIND_IN_SET`, but reconsider your design, some normalisation might be more apt.

Comment: @Wrikken would love to, but im trying to fetch some data from existing opencart database to show on my website.

Comment: Well, just so you know it's generally a bad idea to have more then 1 value in 1 column. If alterations aren't possible, `WHERE FIND_IN_SET(product_id,setting.value)` should work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

To get the details of all `products` which are stored in your `settings` table (comma separated) you can use [**FIND_IN_SET()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
SELECT
    product_description.description, 
    product.name,
    product.id
FROM
    product_description, product
WHERE
    product_description.id = product.id
    AND FIND_IN_SET(product.id, ( SELECT value FROM setting where `key` = 'featured' ) );
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/14042/1)

**Note:** The reason why you see duplicated entries could be because there are multiple descrioptions for a particular product, you can handle this using [**GROUP_CONCAT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)
The following should work

### Epilogue

Your **database design** is not good, It should be something like

```
product             -- All my products go here
product_details     -- Details of all the products ( A product could have multiple details)
categories          -- eg: Featured, Seasonal
product_categories  -- association of product to categories
```

Answer (score 1):

This is somehow breaking the relational paradigm, you should have three entries with values 23, 43 and 28.

Then again I'm guessing field `value` is a varchar (do you know "value" and "key" are reserved words by mysql ?) so you might want to look inside the string to find pattern ",23," inside the field. Something like : `WHERE CONCAT(',', field_value, ',') LIKE "%,23,%"`